# How can I use Python to automate setting bones to be driven by empties?

Tags: python, animation, drivers, fcurves, motion-capture

I have about 30 control bones of a rig that I want to animate using mocap tracker empties.

I will be doing this many times for many models and each time, I need to set and calibrate the drivers for the bones. So I would like to automate the process as much as possible.

The empties are all parented to a reference empty and I need to use the local space coordinates in the drivers.

Specifically, I'd like to:

1. Set coordinates of the location of each bone to be driven by local space coordinates of its related empty.
2. For a specified frame, find the coordinates of the empty and set its keyed value to 0 on the f-curve

One thing that might help in this process is that the empties are mostly named the same as the bones with an added prefix; e.g. the bone "c_nose_02.x" is driven by the empty "mt.c_nose_02.x".

To make this clearer, this is what I am currently doing manually:

1. Add drivers to the relevant coordinates of the bone.

[image]

2. In the Drivers Editor, set the var object to the relevant empty,
3. Choose the matching coordinate and select Local Space
4. Note the value at the default frame

[image]
5. On the f-curve, set a keyframe of that value to 0.

[image]

I'm reasonably fluent in Python, but haven't used it much to automate Blender yet.

As always, any advice or pointers would be most appreciated.

Comment: Rather than changing the FCurve's key frame, I think it's smarter to change the python expression, like var-0.033.

Comment: Thanks @tetii - I didn't mention it in the question but the reason f-curves are necessary is because the movement is not linear. So yes, a simple formula in the expression would zero the bone in default position, but after that I will add max an min coordinates. And I've found that using a combination of formula and f-curve keys makes the process more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've worked it out, after a lot of research, trial and error...

```
pb = obj.pose.bones['c_nose_02.x'] #get pose_bone
pb.driver_remove('location') #remove old drivers

#Add drivers to the relevant coordinates of the bone.
driver_locx = pb.driver_add('location', 0) 
driver_locz = pb.driver_add('location', 2)

#For some reason, that causes f-curve modifiers to be inserted by default, which need to be removed
modx = driver_locx.modifiers[0] 
driver_locx.modifiers.remove(modx)
modz = driver_locz.modifiers[0]
driver_locz.modifiers.remove(modz)

#Set the variables to the relevant empties, choose the matching coordinate and select Local Space
varx = driver_locx.driver.variables.new()
varx.name = "varx"
varx.type = "TRANSFORMS"
tx = varx.targets[0]
tx.id = bpy.data.objects.get('mt.c_nose_02.x')
tx.transform_type = 'LOC_X'
tx.transform_space = 'LOCAL_SPACE'
driver_locx.driver.expression = "varx"

varz = driver_locz.driver.variables.new()
varz.name = "varz"
varz.type = "TRANSFORMS"
tz = varz.targets[0]
tz.id = bpy.data.objects.get('mt.c_nose_02.x')
tz.transform_type = 'LOC_Z'
tz.transform_space = 'LOCAL_SPACE' 
driver_locz.driver.expression = "varz" 

#Get the value of the default frame (actually had to get it from the empty)
#On the f-curve, set a keyframe of that value to 0.
offset_x = tx.id.location.x
driver_locx.keyframe_points.insert(offset_x, 0.0, keyframe_type='KEYFRAME' )

offset_z = tz.id.location.z
driver_locz.keyframe_points.insert(offset_z, 0.0, keyframe_type='KEYFRAME' )
```

After testing this code successfully, I set up an array of all bones that I wanted to control with mocap and used that to make a for loop.